# sorl-thumbnail - Slow template rendering

Tags: django, performance, django-templates, sorl-thumbnail

I have serious performing problem with my templates. After some test, I found out that the slowest part from the rendering was the thumbnails, generated from sorl-thumbnail. 
Below is the issued part from my template:

```
{% for listing in listings %}
    <li class="pic_view">
        <ul>
            <li class="picture">
                <a href="{% url 'listing' listing.id listing.title %}">
                    {% thumbnail listing.get_picture "240x143" crop="center" as im %}
                        <img src="{{ im.url }}">
                    {% empty %}
                        tc
                    {% endthumbnail %}
                    <div class="overlay"></div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="artist">
                <a href="{% url 'profile_artist' listing.artist_id listing.artist.user.first_name %}">
                    {% thumbnail listing.artist.get_avatar "60x60" crop="center" as im %}
                        <img src="{{ im.url }}">
                    {% empty %}
                        tc
                    {% endthumbnail %}
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Currently I have about 6 listings and below is the measured time for rendering:

```
- 8512 ms on first rendering
- 4680 ms on reload
-  112 ms when thumbnail tags are removed
```

Can you please give me some advice on this point. The number above are measured with `Debug=True`, but there is no difference when the flag is False. Also accordingly to `Django` documentation, I have included the followings `TEMPLATE_LOADERS`:

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    ('django.template.loaders.cached.Loader', (
        'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
        'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    )),
  )
```

Comment: What kind of backend do you use for the sorl? there are different options but I believe memcached or redis should be quicker than using the DB especially if you have many entries.

Answer (score 0):

Sorl does this behind the scenes (the chapter in the docs are [here](http://sorl-thumbnail.readthedocs.org/en/latest/operation.html), here is the TL;DR version)

1. Compute a hash value from the original file name and the options
   given
2. Check in the database if that hash is already present, if so,
   deliver associated thumbnail
3. If not, resize the image, store it in the media location, create a
   database record with the hash/filename association, deliver
   thumbnail

That being said, 4.5 seconds for a couple of database lookups is wayyyyyy too long. There is something else going on here.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I cannot find any reason for it. I have checked the time for the queries, and even when the thumbnails tags are added, the time is about 32ms-40ms.

Answer (score 0):

Sorl Thumbnail generates thumbnails on the fly hence time consuming operation, what you need is to create the thumbnails using cronjob or celery (preferred) with the preferred sizes. There is package already called [sorl-thumbnail-async](https://github.com/chhantyal/sorl-thumbnail-async) which does what you are looking for and uses celery. So if the thumbnails are not available show dummy image as soon as the thumbnails are available they will be rendered. Also use memcached as a cache backend for django which is really good in terms of performance.

Comment: First load would generate the images and subsequent loads would be from the cache.  The issue the OP is having is on subsequent loads and is unrelated to image generation.